# How to write junit test for a rest controller having static method call

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito, static-classes

I am trying to write a test class for a controller which is having a static method call.
I have used camel producer template to get the result.

I have tried with Mockito but none of them worked for me:

```
@RestController
@Api(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestController{

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    @ApiOperation(value = "getdata", notes = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PostMapping("/getData" )
    public ApiResponse<Data> getData(@RequestBody DataRequest request, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return ApiUtil.makeCall(producerTemplate, "direct:getdata", request,
                headers, response);
    }
}
```

```
public static ApiResponse makeCall(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, String routerName, Object request,
                                            HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HashMap<String, Object> headersMap = null;

    ApiResponse apiResponse = producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(routerName, request, headersMap, ApiResponse.class);

    response.setStatus(apiResponse.getHttpCode());

    return apiResponse;
}
```

How can I create unit test case for this controller with static method?

Answer (score 1):

Mockito should be fine here (unless `ProducerTemplate` is a final class):

```
@Mock 
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplateStub;

@InjectMocks
private TestController testConstrollerSUT;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception(){

    // Arrange
    when(producerTempalteStub.requestBodyAndHeaders(
           eq(routerName), eq(request), any(Map.class), eq(ApiResponse.class)))
    .thenReturn(myResponse)
```

The bottom line is the static method is trivial enough that it does not need to be mocked itself.